# A method to modify link url in ruby

Tags: ruby

i want to make a method named **url_change**. so that it returns the url with anything after the  (#) removed. 
Example:

```
url_change('www.localhost.com#about')
# returns 'www.localhost.com'
```

Previously, i did this,but its not working well.

```
def url_change(url)
  if url.include? '#'
    url.slice!(/#./)
    return url
  else
    return url
  end
end
```

and also,

```
def url_change(url)
    url.split("#")
end
```

what's the problem here??
will you please show me some way?

Comment: Define "not working well" please

Comment: Fyi, Ruby has tools for working with URIs in its standard library: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html

Comment: @Vache, first method return me "www.localhost.combout"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use pre-existing tools:

```
require 'uri'

def url_change(url)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  uri.fragment = nil
  uri.to_s
end

url_change('http://www.example.com#1') # => "http://www.example.com"
```

It works whether or not the URL contains the scheme:

```
url_change('www.example.com#1') # => "www.example.com"
```

[URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) is part of Ruby's Standard Library, and is well tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
def url_change(url)
  url.split('#', 2).first
end
```

You should probably provide a more descriptive name for the method, such as `remove_fragment`. As others have suggested, it may also be better to use the URI module in the stdlib.

Comment: thanks for your response. your method in working.But i don't understand why should i use  (.first)  . will you please explain me?

Comment: Take a look at [String#split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-split) and [Array#first](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-first). However, you should use the answer below instead, rather than creating your own custom url parser. It has the advantage of making your _intent_ clearer, as well as being well tested.